# Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, integer-overflow

I have a query:

```
update `shops` set
    `points` = `points` - 2,
    `updated_at` = '2019-04-17 23:07:11'
where `id` = 4;
```

Column points have a column type: BIGINT(20).

Now in record I have value 62. When I run the above query I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED
>   value is out of range in '(`database`.`shops`.`points` - 2)'

Is different.

Comment: Do you have a value in `points` that is `0` or `null`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698613/bigint-unsigned-value-is-out-of-range-my-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BIGINT UNSIGNED VALUE IS out of range My SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698613/bigint-unsigned-value-is-out-of-range-my-sql)

Comment: @Shawn I have value: 62, but default is 0

Comment: I would contend that you are hitting a record that is pulling a default value of `0` before the subtraction, making -2 an invalid unsigned integer.

Comment: _BIGINT **UNSIGNED**_ cannot store negative values. Perhaps subtraction resulted in a negatve value.

Comment: ...`CAST(\`shops\` set \`points\` = \`points\` - 2 AS SIGNED)`...

Comment: That would work to see it, but then it still couldn't insert the value back into the column if it's an unsigned datatype

Comment: True, might even be able to handle the issue with `- 2.0` instead of `- 2`

Comment: what is  the updated_at type;

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e9597f4b4d072cf72f5906fe0eb61c14

Comment: `"Column points have a column type: BIGINT(20)."` Your error message indicates that `points` is actually a `BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

```
 set `points` = `points` - cast(2 AS SIGNED)
```

and

```
`updated_at` = '2019-04-17 23:07:11'
```

Comment: Not sure how that would work. It would still try to insert a -2 into a column that is an `unsigned` datatype. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8d07f56083557e4b336374dc02ddb77d

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store negative values in an unsigned integer. The safer solution is to check the operands before performing the subtraction:

```
SET points = CASE WHEN points >= 2 THEN points - 2 ELSE 0 END
```

Or simply:

```
SET points = points - LEAST(points, 2)
```

Comment: Or: `UPDATE shops SET points = points - 2, updated_at = '2019-04-17 
23:07:11' WHERE id = 4 AND points >= 2;`