# Getting Numeric value out of range, but I've created it BigInt

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table, and one of the columns is request_id, which is defined in a migration like this:

```
$table->bigInteger('request_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
```

And when I look on phpmyadmin at the table structure, it says

```
bigint(20)      UNSIGNED
```

I'm making a request to my api, and sending through this value: `1562247865319`

```
$requestLog = new RequestLog();
$requestLog->request_id = 1562247865319;
$requestLog->save();
```

This code is erroring and sending back Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range

What's really strange is that when I'm in phpmyadmin, I can manually set the value of that column to much bigger values than 1562247865319, but when I do it through my laravel model it doesn't like it.

edit

error message is

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'request_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `request_logs` (`ip`, `submitted_user_name`, `url`, `full_url`, `method`, `request_id`, `request_data`, `api_user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (..., ..., ..., http://..../api/..., POST, 1562247865319, {"request_id":"1562248616206"}, 2, 2019-07-04 14:57:00, 2019-07-04 14:57:00))
```

Comment: Please can we ALWAYS see the full and complete error message! Not a summary of it

Comment: What's your `PHP_INT_MAX` value?

Comment: @Haru int size 8, int max 9223372036854775807

Comment: @TKoL Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is the same than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605085/bigint-unsigned-value-is-out-of-range).

Try to change any UNSIGNED ints to SIGNED.

Comment: When I changed it to signed and added it to the column, it made the value negative for some reason...

Comment: Is it the same number though?

Comment: sorry, NO, it is not the same value

Comment: I try to assign 1562247865319 and it's stored as -1120230425